# Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'

Tags: angular, angular6

Here is my Code of employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { IEmployee } from '../employee';
import { Observable, EMPTY, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmployeeService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient){}


  private _url = './assets/data/employee.json';

  getEmployee(): Observable <IEmployee[]>{
    return this.http.get<IEmployee[]>(this._url)
      .catchError(this.errorHandler);
      }

    errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse){
      return Observable.throwError(error.message || 'Server Error');
      }

}
```

and I got an error here

> ERROR in src/app/services/employee.service.ts(20,8): error TS2339: Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

even i import the **catchError** and **throwError**, but still, there is a problem, can anyone help me out from this. I'm using angular6.

Comment: @AJT_82 I already see that answer, but that answer does not help me because the error is still there.

Comment: Then please edit your question and show us what you have tried :)

Comment: it give the error when i pointout the curson on catchError "Property 'catchError' does not exist on type 'Observable<IEmployee[]>'"

Comment: IEmployee is Interface btw.

Comment: well did you put the `pipe` there? Show your code which you tried.

Comment: Well, it's done now. i didn't apply pipe in a code. btw Thank you :)